# compute SVD using Matlab function

Tags: matlab, svd

I have a doubt about SVD. in the literature that i had read, it's written that we have to convert our input matrix into covariance matrix first, and then SVD function from matlab (**SVD**) is used.

But, in Mathworks website we can use SVD function directly to the input matrix (no need to convert it into covariance matrix)..

```
   [U,S,V]=svd(inImageD);
```

1. Which one is the true??
2. And if we want to do dimensionality reduction, we have to project our data into eigen vector.. But where is the eigen vector generated by SVD function..
   I know that S is the eigen value.. But what is U and S??
3. To reduce our data dimensional, do we need to substract the input matrix with its mean and then multiply it with eigen vector?? or we can just multiply our input matrix with the eigen vector (no need to substract it first with its mean)..

---

**EDIT**

Suppose if I want to do classification using SIFT as the features and SVM as the classifier.

I have 10 images for training and I arrange them in a different row..

So 1st row for 1st images, 2nd row for second images and so on...

```
Feat=[1 2 5 6 7   >> Images1
      2 9 0 6 5   >> Images2
      3 4 7 8 2   >> Images3
      2 3 6 3 1   >> Images4
      ..
      .
      so on. . ]
```

To do dimensionality reduction (from my **10x5** matrix), we have yo do **A*EigenVector**

And from what U had explained (@Sam Roberts), I can compute it by using **EIGS** function from the covariance matrix (instead of using SVD function).

And as I arrange the feat of images in different row, so I need to do **A'*A**
So it becomes:

```
 Matrix=A'*A
 MAT_Cov=Cov(Matrix)
 [EigVector EigValue] = eigs (MAT_Cov);
```

is that right??

Comment: take a look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition

Comment: My answer did not mention the function `eigs` at all. It described the function `eig`, which is different. I also did not suggest that you use either `eig` or `eigs` - I just described how EVD can be seen as equivalent to SVD. If I were in your position, I would *not* use EVD, I would use SVD. And I wouldn't use the command `svd` for that, I would `pca` or `princomp`.

Comment: Just to be clear, `eigs` is typically used for sparse matrices, whereas `eig` is used for full matrices.

Comment: I become confuse now,,
Can u explain by using an example.
For ex: I have feature matrix A=[1 2 3 4 5 6;9 7 6 5 5 7; 9 8 0 1 2 3;4 5 6 2 1 0]; There I have 3 images with  6 features per each images.. How to do dimensionality reduction??

Answer (score 4):

Eigenvector decomposition (EVD) and singular value decomposition (SVD) are closely related.

Let's say you have some data `a = rand(3,4);`. Note that this not a square matrix - it represents a dataset of observations (rows) and variables (columns).

Do the following:

```
[u1,s1,v1] = svd(a);
[u2,s2,v2] = svd(a');
[e1,d1] = eig(a*a');
[e2,d2] = eig(a'*a);
```

Now note a few things.

1. Up to the sign (+/-), which is arbitrary, `u1` is the same as `v2`. Up to a sign and an ordering of the columns, they are also equal to `e1`. (Note that there may be some very very tiny numerical differences as well, due to slight differences in the `svd` and `eig` algorithms).
2. Similarly, `u2` is the same as `v1` and `e2`.
3. `s1` equals `s2`, and apart from some extra columns and rows of zeros, both also equal `sqrt(d1)` and `sqrt(d2)`. Again, there may be some very tiny numerical differences as well just due to algorithmic issues (they'll be on the order of something to the -10 or so).

Note also that `a*a'` is basically the covariances of the rows, and `a'*a` is basically the covariances of the columns (that's not quite true - `a` would need to be centred first by subtracting the column or row mean for them to be equal, and there might be a multiplicative constant difference as well, but it's basically pretty similar).

Now to answer your questions, I assume that what you're really trying to do is PCA. You can do PCA *either* by taking the original data matrix and applying SVD, *or* by taking its covariance matrix and applying EVD. Note that Statistics Toolbox has two functions for PCA - `pca` (in older versions `princomp`) and `pcacov`.

Both do essentially the same thing, but from different starting points, because of the above equivalences between SVD and EVD.

Strictly speaking, `u1`, `v1`, `u2` and `v2` above are *not* eigenvectors, they are singular vectors - and `s1` and `s2` are singular values. They are singular vectors/values of the matrix `a`. `e1` and `d1` are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `a*a'` (not `a`), and `e2` and `d2` are the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `a'*a` (not `a`). `a` does not have any eigenvectors - only square matrices have eigenvectors.

Centring by subtracting the mean is a separate issue - you would typically do that prior to PCA, but there are situations where you wouldn't want to. You might also want to normalise by dividing by the standard deviation but again, you wouldn't always want to - it depends what the data represents and what question you're trying to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get any notif abt this before, So I didnt know that u had answered it..
And thanks that you answered it in good way..
But I just wanna make it clear by using an example,,
Suppose if I want to do classification using SIFT as the features and SVM as the classifier.
I have 10 images for training..

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get any notif abt this before, So I didnt know that u had answered it..
And thanks that you answered it in good way..
But I just wanna make it clear by using an example,,
As it is too long, I wrote them in my question in EDIT section,,
Please have a look at it,,
And im going to accept ur answer for it..
Just need to make it clear